# unix PATH environment variable edit

Tags: unix

My PATH environment variable right now is:

./subTmp:/usr/local/bin

How do I remove the ./subTmp part from it?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a rather strange PATH; usually they include `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details vary a bit by installation and by local custom, but generally you have a file named either .profile, .login, or .bashrc in your home directory that contains a line something like

```
PATH = ./subTmp:/usr/local/bin
```

Just edit it to be whatever you need.

Comment: Why on earth are you using an obscure term like that? Almost everyone who reads it will have to google it.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I forgot who I was talking to for a minute. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin
```